# Label text not updating when bound to property

Tags: c#, winforms, inotifypropertychanged

I have to update the text of a `Label`. I have bound the Text property of `Label` to a property and implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` event.

My code is as follows:

```
public partial class MyClass : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _text;

    public string ucText
    {
        get
        {
            return _text;
        }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ucText");
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public MyClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblText.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this, "ucText"));
    }
}
```

In a `Button` click event in another form, I update the text of the `Label` as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        myClass1.ucText = i.ToString();

    }
}
```

Here myClass1 is object of the `UserControl` posted above.

In the `Button` click event, the UI hangs when updating the label and then once the loop completes, shows the final value:

> 9999

Why is my UI not reactive? I have also tried

`lblText.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this, "ucText", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));`

Comment: Your UI thread is blocked while you are in that loop and only updates once you return from the click handler.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @CharlesMager I believe he's just testing the binding, and wants to see his label getting updated in real time.

Comment: I have to update the label value. I have written the for loop to test my code

Comment: @Abhishek your problem has been resolved numerous times already. You've got to use a Thread.Run or a BackgroundWorker in your click event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are running on the same thread, the UI thread. The following scenario is happening:

1. Button is clicked
2. Change text to i
3. Notify UI
4. Increment i
5. Go to 2. if i < 10000
6. Refresh the UI

As long as the loop isn't done, the UI thread won't redraw, as it's still doing some "heavy" work.

You can of course let a new thread handle the "calculation" and let that thread change the value. To start a new thread use either a backgroundworker or start a new thread with the Thread class.

The binding you are using is in fact working.

Edit: Always remember that all calculation that is directly done on the UI thread will block the UI for the time the calculation needs. Always use other threads to do time intensive calculations.